# advice on improving the structure of a loop

Tags: javascript, performance

I am hoping that would a kind soul out there that might be able to provide a little guidance to improve my working knowledge.

Two questions

- Is there a way to produce a faster loop? I see K runs 4 times for every I?
- I have struggled to find an equivalent of `break;` or a means to shortcut/exit a ES6 `forEach`. Could anyone point me to a more modern loop syntax than my combo of old school loops?  The two nested i's and k's - as the author struggle to track my code.

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll('#ul > li');
let arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
for (let k=0; k < list.length; k++) {
    for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (k >= arr.length) {
            list[k].textContent = '';
        } else {
            list[i].textContent = arr[i];
            console.log(`k loop no: ${k} / i loop no: ${i}`);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<ul id='ul'>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should tag your request with the language in question to get attention. Is this JavaScript?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You are most correct; thank you for spotting my error. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, it looks as though you are trying to map a string to an element found in the DOM. The approach that you've used isn't an approach that lends itself towards predictability and consistency, because the DOMcould change at any point in the future, and you will have to update your algorithm.

Assuming that this is your DOM, it won't change in the future, you can eliminate the `i` iteration, since `i` is only checking for whether or not the index is greater. This instead of easily achieved by `Array.length`

eg.

```js
[1,2,3,4].length === 4 // returns true
```

We can replace the for loop with the `NodeList.forEach` function, and check if the index of the list is greater than the length of the values array.

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll('#ul > li');
const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
list.forEach((ele, idx) => {
  if (idx > arr.length) {
    return;
  }
  ele.textContent = arr[idx];
});
```

See working example:
https://codepen.io/jmitchell38488/pen/VwejXRK

Comment: thank you for your considered response and code. It worked the first time and I learnt something new. I hope you enjoy the remainder of your weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Nested loops are like nested baby birds. You have to be very careful with them, and there's a whole lot of vomit involved. My recommendation is to always have some cleaning solution and a towel that you don't mind getting dirty on hand.

In your case, much like a young girl at her junior prom, you've thrown up a couple of times. Whether it be due to a small, empty belly, nerves, or the naivety of youth, who can say? Note that I'm making the assumption here that your goal is to update your `<li>` elements to the be the human English spelling of their ordinal values. It is a practice I am familiar with, as it is also a hobby of mine that I enjoy during these long summer days.

Your first expulsion is you've mixed your `k` and `i` values when indexing into `list`. However, even accounting for that will produce the wrong result, since your vomito numero dos (as they say at the quinceañeras) is really the logic in general as it is ripe for error. My suggestion would be not to nest loops or worry about `break`, and instead to index directly into `arr`. Here's something that may settle your metaphorical stomach.

```
let list = document.querySelectorAll('#ul > li');
let arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
for (let k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
  if (k >= arr.length) {
    list[k].textContent = '';
  } else { 
    list[k].textContent = arr[k];
  }
}
```